# YAML syntax error occurred while parsing config/database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

> Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs
>   are not allowed.
>
> Error: (): found character that cannot start any token while
>   scanning for the next token at line 17 column 13
>
> Ruby version is : ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769)
>   [x86_64-linux] Rails version is : Rails 4.2.3

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

Full `database.yml` file:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 5.0+ are recommended.
#
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
 <<: *default
 database: readit_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: readit_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: readit_production
  username: readit
  password: <%= ENV['READIT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: The error is at line 17, I supposed it is the password line. Maybe a typo error there like a space character try removing the spaces after the 'password:'.

Comment: Something hidden in your file. I just copy/pasted the above and am able to import it just fine on OSX with ruby 2.2.2p95.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like either an error in the parser that you are using, or, as Philip suggested, a hidden character.

Using

```
yaml round-trip database.yml
```

you get no parser error, and the same output as the input file, except for the empty lines (dropped) and the mapping value of `development` which is inconsistently indented at 1 space (but that is not a YAML error, as it only requires consistent indenting within the same mapping/sequence).

Answer (score 0):

In password field give single space.

ex:

```
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5 
username: root  
password:_*****
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution to know if your YAML is correct

http://www.yamllint.com/

Paste in your YAML and click "Go" - we'll tell you if it's valid or not, and give you a nice clean UTF-8 version of it. Optimized for Ruby.

Comment: It seems like the person asking the question already knows that the YAML is invalid. Your answer does not answer his "why" question

Comment: i had the same error and this page doesn't help me, i found a solution on another blog which help me with this linter which point me the solution... and it was an syntax problem. but if you have the solution, please help us, thx